# Axiom of Regularity - Transitive set

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I just managed to confuse myself completely while studying for Set Theory.
We have the Axiom of regularity:
$$\forall S (S\not= \emptyset \rightarrow (\exists x\in S)(S\cap x=\emptyset))$$
Now a set is transitive, if $x\in T$ implies $x\subset T$.
I don't understand anymore how that can be while we have the Axiom of regularity.
Doesn't follow from the definition of a transitive set, that $x\cap T = x$?

Maybe if someone knows a good source for a more detailed explanation of the Axiom of regularity or has the time to explain me some more?

Thanks and best,

Luca

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right. If $x$ is transitive, and $y\in x$ then $x\cap y=y$.

**Hint:** Show that a transitive set $x$ must either be empty, or $\varnothing\in x$.

Comment: Thank you! That sheds light on the dark :)

Comment: Set theory *is* the light in the dark! ;-)

Comment: One more question, is it also possible to prove this without the Axiom of Regularity?
I thought maybe with the Axiom of Dependent Choice? I assume $T\not= \emptyset$ and $\emptyset \not\subset T$. Then I can apply this Axiom. But since $\in$ is well-founded we get a contradicction?
Not sure if I left out some detailes? It just came to my mind...

Comment: Luca, the axiom of choice and its weaker principles have absolutely nothing to do with this sort of thing. And no, you cannot prove this without the axiom of regularity because it is consistent that we have $A=\{A\}$ in which case $A\in A$ and $A\subseteq A$, but $\varnothing\notin A$.

Comment: ok. Thank you for the quick answer! Then I'll forget that quickly and get back to look at the theory more closely.

Comment: @AsafKaragila well, "set theory" is "teorie množin" in Czech, which is commonly abbreviated to "temno" which means the dark :)

Comment: @byk7: Ha! That puts the first comment in a different light. :P

Answer (score 1):

If you have $x \cap S = x$ and want $x \cap S = \varnothing$, putting the two equations together is very instructive....